# Global Maxima of $x^2$ (can infinity be the maxima?)

Tags: maxima-minima

[Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GlobalMaximum.html) defines *Global Maxima* as :

> A global maximum, also known as an absolute maximum, the largest
>   overall value of a set, function, etc., over its entire range.

As per the definition, I'm not sure if $\infty$ can be considered as the global maxima for functions like $x$, $x^2$, etc. What if we consider the extended real number set?

Comment: No. Conventionally "maximum" always means a finite number. In extended real number system though, we accept $\infty$ as possible value for "supremum", but still a "maximum" is always finite.

Comment: @Vim Exactly. The consideration of infinity as supremum led me to such a doubt.

Comment: @Vim: That's an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 3):

You've probably found that when you write infinity in interval notation, you are instructed to write for example $$ y\in [0,\infty) $$
Note how the high bound infinity is not included.  This is because infinity is a boundary not a real number,
$$\infty \not\in \mathbb{R}$$
that is a number can approach but not touch infinity, so it could not be that the maximum is infinity.